# GC - G1 Old Generation 'spike' - finding the cause

Tags: java, garbage-collection, kubernetes

App in question is running on (in?) **Kubernetes (Google container engine)** processing a regular stream of kafka data. The data is evenly divided among all the pods (using a random key to prevent 'hot spots'<sup>1</sup>).

80-90% of the processes will run fine indefinitely but some will show memory issues like these:

[image]

What would cause particular instances of *what should be identical processes* to have these spikes? As I said - the data is homogenous and evenly divided among all the consumers so there is no reason for one instance to be doing more work.

Clearly something is different for these outliers. Something is forcing allocations to be promoted to **Old Gen**. The other pods show (roughly) even <1% **Young Gen** GC during this same period.

Here is a second example from the same time span:

[image]

<sup>1</sup>Other monitoring shows this to be accurate.

Comment: Can you also provide information about memory usage on the node and in  the POD? Also it would be interesting which memory settings you provide to the JVM. My guess is that some of your nodes have less free memory available then others, which is quite normal. As most JVMs are configured to not allocate the maximum allowed memory immediately on startup, JVM heap may fail to grow later when other processes use more memory. The JVM tries to "fix" this with more GC calls, resulting in degradation of performance.